# How ActiveRecord calls 'where'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activesupport

Could you let me know how Active Record calls 'where' when I execute `User.where(id: 1)`?

I'm checking Active Record's functionality to read the source code and stop the process by pry.
I can see when I execute `User.where(id: 1)`, the process goes to
`rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb`

```
delegate :select, :group, :order, :except, :reorder, :limit, :offset, :joins, :left_joins, :left_outer_joins, :or,
         :where, :rewhere, :preload, :eager_load, :includes, :from, :lock, :readonly,
         :having, :create_with, :distinct, :references, :none, :unscope, :merge, to: :all
```

'where' is delegated to :all.
Thus it goes to
`rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb`

```
def all
  if current_scope
   current_scope.clone
  else
    default_scoped
  end
end
```

I don't understand this part. Why it goes to all?
delegate can be set to class method? I though it can be delegated to class variables, instance variables.

after default_scope in scoping/named.rb all method, the process goes to `rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb`

```
def where(opts = :chain, *rest)
  if :chain == opts
    WhereChain.new(spawn)
  elsif opts.blank?
    self
  else
    spawn.where!(opts, *rest)
  end
end
```

Why? Isn't `where` delegated to `:all`? How does it get back to `where`(relation/query_methods.rb)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care about the implementation of the `where` method?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care about why coffee man cares about the implementation of the `where` method?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care about why MrDanA cares about why I care about the implementation of the `where` method? :)

Comment: (Batman voice) It's not what MrDana cares about that defines you. But how you care about what CoffeeMan cares about when TomLord cares about it!

Comment: @bkunzi01 I like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand this part. Why it goes to `all`?

Because:

```
User.where(id: 1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
User.all.where(id: 1)
```

This delegation is to simplify the API, by adding an implicit call to `all` when none is explicitly made.

> How does it get back to `where` (relation/query_methods.rb)?

Remember that this was a *delegation*, not an alias. So, since:

```
User.all
```

returns:

```
User.default_scoped
```

This means that, effectively, this is the method chain being constructed:

```
User.where
--> User.all.where
--> User.default_scoped.where
```

And since `User.default_scoped` is a `User::ActiveRecord_Relation` object, its definition of `#where` is indeed defined in `rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb`, as:

```
def where(opts = :chain, *rest)
  if :chain == opts
    WhereChain.new(spawn)
  elsif opts.blank?
    self
  else
    spawn.where!(opts, *rest)
  end
end
```

...But this is only the beginning of the story. We are still quite a way off constructing the actual SQL for the query.

[Here is a series of blog posts](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/9/17/20000-leagues-under-activerecord) that dive deeper, if you're interested - but I think this goes beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know why `User.where -> User.all.where`? Yes as you pointed out I thought delegate is like alias. Based on this [document](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) delegate to: option specifies the target object. :all is object? It looks like class method. I still cannot understand how the system chain the method like `User.all.where` Isn't it because of delegate? Should I check the other part?

Comment: Remember that in ruby, *everything* is an object. Even methods are objects (https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html)!!! Rather than getting hung up on the word "object" here, just think of it as "delegating `where` to the response of `all`", or in other words `User.where == User.all.where`.

Comment: This is, of course, different to an *alias*. If this were an alias, not a delegation, then it would indeed be `User.where == User.all`. But that's not the case here.